# Unable to SSH to a docker container from docker host

Tags: docker

I have created a docker host on openstack and launched a container with it's port 22 mapped to a port on docker host. Followed this [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/)
Still i can't ssh from docker host to container. It gives this error:

```
$> ssh -v root@172.17.0.9 -p 32775

OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 56: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 172.17.0.9 [172.17.0.9] port 32775.
debug1: connect to address 172.17.0.9 port 32775: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.9 port 32775: Connection refused
```

Iptables rule is added by default when i used -P option in docker run. It looks like this:

```
$> iptables -t nat -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.3           172.17.0.3           tcp dpt:80
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.9           172.17.0.9           tcp dpt:22

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:9090 to:172.17.0.3:80
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:32775 to:172.17.0.9:22
```

And container looks like:

```
$> docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS                   NAMES
46111bb52063        sshns               "/usr/sbin/sshd -D"      9 hours ago         Up 3 hours                 0.0.0.0:32776->22/tcp   TestSSHcontainer
```

I need to have ssh only for my purpose. I'm aware about docker exec option. Tried changes like PermitRootLogin yes on sshd_config and ssh_config on both docker host and container with no success.

```
bash-4.2# /usr/sbin/sshd -Dd
WARNING: 'UsePAM no' is not supported in Red Hat Enterprise Linux and may cause several problems.
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type ECDSA
debug1: private host key: #1 type 3 ECDSA
debug1: private host key: #2 type 4 ED25519
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-Dd'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
Cannot bind any address.

bash-4.2# netstat -anp | grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
bash-4.2# ps -eaf | grep ssh
root         1     0  0 19:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root        26    16  0 22:58 ?        00:00:00 grep ssh
```

Is there something that i'm still missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the ip of your container but the `host port mapping` of container. Try either `ssh -v root@172.17.0.9` or `ssh -v root@localhost -p <port_mapping_on_host>`(*Your `docker ps -a` shows your porting mapping on host is `32776`*)

Comment: Okay great. Thanks. If i'm host so i can use localhost on that port or connect to container IP directly because it's reachable from host. But; if i want to ssh to container from a separate host, then what should i do?                                                                                                                                  <host2># ssh root@<public ip of host1> -p 32776

ssh: connect to host <public ip of host1> port 32776: Connection timed out

Comment: You can ssh to it by `ssh root@<your_host_ip> -p <container_port_mapping_on_host>`

Comment: ssh -v root@localhost -p <port_mapping_on_host> really worked for me